# Height:100% problem in my Flex box css div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Even though I set the `div`'s height covering the image to `100%`, as in the example below, it does not cover the entire block. Another problem is that, when I look at the console, the height of the `.features-img-container` is 189px, while the `.features-img` inside it is 185px. Even though I gave the image `height: 100%`, why doesn't it cover the entire image?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.features {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.features.primary {
  background-color: #9FB29B;
}

.features.secondary {
  background-color: rgb(228, 215, 188);
}

.features-img-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.features-img-container img {
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover !important;
}

.features-content {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 60px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.features-content .wrap {
  width: 96%;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.features-content .mini-text {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.features-content .subtitle {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.features-content .title {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 62px;
  margin-top: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="features secondary">
  <div class="features-content">
    <div class="wrap">

      <div class="mini-text">
        Machines à café avec broyeur
      </div>
      <div class="title">
        Un café plus responsable envers la planète.
      </div>
      <div class="subtitle">
        Nous travaillons directement avec de petits producteurs de café du monde entier pour vous offrir des
        <br> cafés de spécialité de la plus haute qualité. De plus, nous torréfions quotidiennement afin que le café <br> que vous recevez à la maison soit toujours frais.
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="btn">
                                            Connaître nos valeurs
                                        </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="features-img-container">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-         vector/hand-painted-watercolor-pastel-sky-background_23-2148902771.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" class="features-img">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a picture or drawing of your wanted result?

Comment: Do you want to cover image full screen? .features {
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            height: 100vh;
        }

Comment: @mhasan Whatever the height of the ".features-image-container" I want, I want the image inside it (".features-img") to have the same height. However, when I look at it from the console, even though I give height:100% to the container and the image, my container 189px image becomes 185px height. Why? I don't understand, it doesn't completely cover the inside of the container.

Comment: @TamirAbutbul Whatever the height of the ".features-image-container" I want, I want the image inside it (".features-img") to have the same height. However, when I look at it from the console, even though I give height:100% to the container and the image, my container 189px image becomes 185px height. Why? I don't understand, it doesn't completely cover the inside of the container.

Comment: @tokdev0 I answered your question

Comment: try to use ```background-image: url(your image here) cover no-repeat;```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your problem by adding `vertical-align: top;` to your image :

```
 .features-img-container img{
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover !important;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Now when you change the image container height the image height will be the same

```html
    <div class="features secondary">
        <div class="features-content">
            <div class="wrap">

                <div class="mini-text">
                    Machines à café avec broyeur
                </div>
                <div class="title">
                    Un café plus responsable envers la planète.
                </div>
                <div class="subtitle">
                    Nous travaillons directement avec de petits producteurs de café du monde entier pour vous offrir des
                    <br>
                    cafés de spécialité de la plus haute qualité. De plus, nous torréfions quotidiennement afin que le
                    café <br>
                    que vous recevez à la maison soit toujours frais.
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="btn">
                    Connaître nos valeurs
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="features-img-container">
            <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/hand-painted-watercolor-pastel-sky-background_23-2148902771.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" class="features-img">
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <style>
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;

}


.features {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

.features.primary{
    background-color: #9FB29B;

}
.features.secondary{
    background-color: rgb(228, 215, 188);
}

.features-img-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.features-img-container img{
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover !important;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.features-content {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 60px 20px 20px 20px;
}
.features-content .wrap{
    width: 96%;
    max-width: 600px;
}

.features-content .mini-text {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.features-content .subtitle {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-top: 30px;

}

.features-content .title {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 62px;
    margin-top: 90px;
}



    
    
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: block;` to your image – by default images are inline, which leaves some space under the (non-visible) baseline:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.features {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.features.primary {
  background-color: #9FB29B;
}

.features.secondary {
  background-color: rgb(228, 215, 188);
}

.features-img-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.features-img-container img {
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover !important;
  display: block;
}

.features-content {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 60px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.features-content .wrap {
  width: 96%;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.features-content .mini-text {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.features-content .subtitle {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.features-content .title {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 62px;
  margin-top: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="features secondary">
  <div class="features-content">
    <div class="wrap">

      <div class="mini-text">
        Machines à café avec broyeur
      </div>
      <div class="title">
        Un café plus responsable envers la planète.
      </div>
      <div class="subtitle">
        Nous travaillons directement avec de petits producteurs de café du monde entier pour vous offrir des
        <br> cafés de spécialité de la plus haute qualité. De plus, nous torréfions quotidiennement afin que le café <br> que vous recevez à la maison soit toujours frais.
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="btn">
                                            Connaître nos valeurs
                                        </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="features-img-container">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-         vector/hand-painted-watercolor-pastel-sky-background_23-2148902771.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" class="features-img">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: block;` or `vertical-align:middle;` to your `.features-img-container img`. The extra space you are seeing is there by design - the image is inline and by default has space equivalent to descender in a font. This is so images align with the baseline of text by default.

Changing the image to block or telling it where to align will override this behaviour.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.features {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.features.primary {
  background-color: #9FB29B;
}

.features.secondary {
  background-color: rgb(228, 215, 188);
}

.features-img-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.features-img-container img {
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover !important;
  display: block;
}

.features-content {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 60px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.features-content .wrap {
  width: 96%;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.features-content .mini-text {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.features-content .subtitle {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.features-content .title {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 62px;
  margin-top: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="features secondary">
  <div class="features-content">
    <div class="wrap">

      <div class="mini-text">
        Machines à café avec broyeur
      </div>
      <div class="title">
        Un café plus responsable envers la planète.
      </div>
      <div class="subtitle">
        Nous travaillons directement avec de petits producteurs de café du monde entier pour vous offrir des
        <br> cafés de spécialité de la plus haute qualité. De plus, nous torréfions quotidiennement afin que le café <br> que vous recevez à la maison soit toujours frais.
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="btn">
                                            Connaître nos valeurs
                                        </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="features-img-container">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-         vector/hand-painted-watercolor-pastel-sky-background_23-2148902771.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" class="features-img">
  </div>
</div>
```